# Is It Possible to Prioritise Resource Files In vb.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, resources, globalization, resx

I have a vb.Net website that is set up to handle multiple languages. All the text content is held in the global resource file: Resource.resx

There are other resource files set up such as; Resource.nl-NL.resx & Resource.es-ES.resx that contain the content for cultures other than the default: English.

When the application runs .Net kindly pulls all the text from the correct resource file, according to the users culture. If the resource for that culture does not exist, the data held in the default Resource.resx file is used. This all works as it should.

My problem is that now, I have been asked that some of the website text be different when the website is viewed by a specific type of user (regardless of culture). So now I find myself with another recourse file Resource2.resx, which could also have alternate cultures; Resource2.nl-NL.resx & Resource2.es-ES.resx

Is there a way to set up the site to first use Resource2.resx, but then fall back on Resource.resx if the key does not exist? I can do this by specifying the text for each control manually in the code behind, but it's a pain...